# rsync daemon stopped working a few days ago - some update has broken it

Tags: rsync

I have an rsync daemon on a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 which I use for daily backups.  Daily backups stopped working on  22nd January with the following error:-

```
@ERROR: access denied to esprimo from esprimo.zbmc.eu (192.168.1.3)
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1675) [sender=3.1.3]
```

The rsyncd log just has:-

```
2020/01/24 08:37:01 [973] connect from esprimo.zbmc.eu (192.168.1.3)
2020/01/24 08:37:01 [973] rsync denied on module esprimo from esprimo.zbmc.eu (192.168.1.3)
```

Presumably something somewhere has got updated and tightened up some sort of permission requirement but I've searched through quite a few reports of this error and can't find the culprit. Can anyone come up with possible reasons for this that I might have missed and/or recent updates that might have affected rsyncd.

Comment: your rsyncd.conf?

Comment: I can't see how to post it as a comment, I'll try in a further comment.

Comment: `#
#
# rsync daemon configuration file
#
use chroot = no
secrets file = /home/chris/rsyncd/secrets
pid file = /home/chris/tmp/pid
timeout = 300
strict modes = false
uid = root
pre-xfer exec = /home/chris/bin/prebak.py
post-xfer exec = /home/chris/bin/postbak.py
log file = /home/chris/rsyncd/log

#
#
# My desktop machine
#
[esprimo]
    hosts allow = esprimo
    hosts deny = *
    path = /b2/esprimo/today
    comment = For back up of desktop machine
    refuse options = delete
    read only = false
#    auth users = chris
`

Comment: No, oh well, you can probably see what it contains.  I commented out the 'auth users' line to see if that would help but my backup is still failing with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong though I don't quite understand what changed.

The 'hosts allow' parameter specified the unqualified name of the connecting computer, e.g. for the first entry it was 'esprimo'.  Changing this to the fully qualified domain name esprimo.zbmc.eu has fixed the error and now my backups are working again.

I'm not clear if rsync got stricter on checking names or if my local DNS has started returning fully qualified names (this is just on my home LAN so normally I just call 'esprimo' by its short name).